# How can I add multiple tables with jQuery tabs to a single page?

Tags: jquery, tabs

As the title suggests, I am trying to add two separate tabbed tables to a single page, using the following jQuery script (which I found [here](http://howtodomssqlcsharpexcelaccess.blogspot.com/2018/02/mvc-jquery-simple-tabs-example.html)):

```
<div class="firstTable">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Some Text 1<br /> </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Some Text 2<br />very important</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Some Text 3<br />garbage</div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Some Text 4<br />something else</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
</script>
```

This works perfectly well for one table, with it flawlessly switching to whichever tab is selected.

However, when I try to incorporate a second tabbed table into the same page, as seen below, things don't go as smoothly:

```
<div class="firstTable">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Some Text 1<br /> </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Some Text 2<br />very important</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Some Text 3<br />garbage</div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Some Text 4<br />something else</div>
</div>

<div class="secondTable">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Some Text 1<br /> </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Some Text 2<br />very important</div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Some Text 3<br />garbage</div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Some Text 4<br />something else</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    });
</script>
```

Everything loads correctly, with the first tab of each table being correctly selected and the correct data being shown below in the table. But when I click on any of the tabs of either table, the other table disappears due to following line:

```
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
```

From this point, I can only display one table at a time until I refresh the page.

Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding a work around... does anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:** The issue was solved by [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) who suggested that I add an additional class selector:

```
$(".secondTable .tab-content").removeClass("current");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add an additional class selector: `$(".secondTable .tab-content").removeClass("current");`   Also, give your tabs different numbers (the 2nd set start at tab-5)

Comment: As freedom implies, you can't have elements with the same `id` attribute on a page as jquery will choose only one of the elements with that id. So they have to be unique.

Comment: You have multiple `div`s with the same `id`, which is not valid HTML and confusing the tab plugin.  U*se different pairs of `id` and `data-tab` for each set of tabs.

Comment: Although I didn't show it in the code above, I did have different numbers for my tabs (with the second set starting at tab-5). However, adding the additional class selector as freedomn-m suggested worked! Thank you!